# UITableView cell with collection view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, custom-cell

I have created a .xib file for TableView cell, and I want to add a collection view into that cell. [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OHtX.png) The gray rectangle shown in the picture is a collection view, my question is why the collection view doesn't show a prototype cell. What did I do wrong? Or this is what it should be, then how can I add a prototype cell? By making another .xib file for the UICollectionVew Cell?

Answer (score 1):

> my question is why the collection view doesn't show a prototype cell

Because it's a *.xib*. Prototype cells are a storyboard feature.

Comment: Does that mean that I need to create another .xib for the collection cell?

Comment: It doesn't "mean" you "need" to do anything, since nothing is wrong. You certainly _can_ create a _.xib_ if you have a custom collection view cell that you want to design visually.